# Calculating Retention using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, count, retention

I am currently trying to calculate the retention rate (percentage of customers that returned to a webpage) of 3 days for in a entire table within the span of 14 days. To do so, I am trying to count the total user (visitorId) of whom returned to the page between specific dates, then I would average them together in order to have the the average retention rate for the 14 days. Currently I am using this code but it does not seem to work.

```
SELECT
    pageviews.pageType,
    pageviews.pageviewDate,
    sessions.sessionDate,
    sessions.deviceType,
    sessions.visitorId
    AVG(COUNT(sessions.visitor > 1 BETWEEN sessions.sessionDate '2018-04-26' AND '2018-04-29')
    # There would be multiple of these dates
FROM sessions
INNER JOIN pageviews
    ON sessions.visitorId = pageviews.visitorId AND
       pageviews.pageviewDate = sessions.sessionDate
WHERE
    pageviews.pageType = 'Game' AND sessions.deviceType = 'Desktop';
```

To be more specific, the desired result would be to have a single number that states the average number of customers that returned to a specific page (in this case, Game) that used Desktops. Can anyone help? Please let me know if more clarification is needed. Note, for simplicity, I did not add all the date that I would calculate the retention rate as it would be many.

Comment: Adding some sample data might help.  It would be difficult for someone to learn your data only from this query.

Comment: To be more specific, lets say that Customers A,B, and C when to the site between April 4th 2018. On April 27th, only customer A returned. Essentially, I want to count the number of customers who returned within 3 days and average them together.

Comment: Your question is not clear. For instance, suppose the date range goes from 2018-04-04 to 2018-04-18, so your **3 days** would mean: 4-7, 5-8, 5-9... 16-18. Are you asking to check within all these ranges? You will need to be at more clear and specific.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: @TheLeveyBreaks . . . Your comments are no clearer.  Your question has "3 days", "14 days", and a date range.  I can't figure out how to put them together to understand anything regarding what I would call "retention". Sample data and desired results help.